# Gradle: shade guava without losing transitive dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, gradle, guava, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have a multi-module Gradle project. One module (A) contains database-related classes; another (B) contains Spark applications and depends on A.

Spark depends on Guava 14.x. My database classes depend on Guava 28.x.

I need to be able to use Guava 28.x in my database module, and declare that module as a project dependency in the Spark module.

Shading (and relocating) Guava in module A is easy enough:

```
shadowJar {
    configurations = [project.configurations.shadow] // this was done to prevent ALL of A's dependencies from being shaded
    relocate 'com.google.common', 'shaded.com.google.common'
}
dependencies {
    shadow 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'
}
```

But, when I declare module A as a dependency in B, such as:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':A')
}
```

The JAR that ends up on B's `runtimeClasspath` is the *unshaded* JAR of A.

When I specify the shaded JAR, such as:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project( path: ':A', configuration: 'shadow' )
}
```

None of A's transitive dependencies are available on B's `runtimeClasspath`.

My goal is to shade and relocate *only* Guava in module A, to minimize JAR size and build time. I then need that shaded JAR as well as A's transitive dependencies available on B's `runtimeClasspath`.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat-unsatisfying solution is to just declare in B the transitive dependencies I need from A. Because the set of dependencies is relatively small, this might be the best approach for this project; but I'd prefer something more elegant.

Maybe my reliance on transitivity is fraught? I've enjoyed doing so because it keeps the `dependencies` terse throughout the modules of this project, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.